# Responsive design, max-width not working

Tags: html, css

I have been working with html/css and I have an issue with html css. In mobile devices my html/css look like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/goHC8.png

I have pointed the issue. Why this happens?

My HTML:

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
       v2.0 | 20110126
       License: none (public domain)
    */

html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block;
}
body {
  line-height: 1.6;
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
/*
    â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”
    */

html {
  background: #000000;
  background: url(back.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
#portrait {} body {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  width: 380pt;
  margin: 32pt;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
}
#imagebox {
  text-align: left;
  margin: 2pt;
  transition: 0.5s all ease;
}
p {
  padding-bottom: 1.2em;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 20pt;
  margin-top: 10pt;
  margin-bottom: 3pt;
  font-weight: 200;
}
h2 {
  margin-top: 20pt;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 12pt;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
a:link {
  /* color: #00aaff;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 1s all ease;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
a:visited {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  transition: 2s all ease;
}
a:hover {
  color: #00aaff;
  transition: 0.2s all ease;
}
/*
    â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”â€”
    */

/* iPad */

@media screen and (max-width: 640pt) {
  html {
    background: url(back.jpg) no-repeat left center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  #portrait {
    background: url(back.jpg) no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 260px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-top: 40px;
  }
  body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 12pt;
    background-color: rgb(19, 19, 19);
    height: 100%;
  }
  #imagebox {
    transition: 0.5s all ease;
    margin: 30pt 30pt 0pt 32pt;
  }
  #box {
    margin: 0pt 30pt 30pt 30pt;
  }
}
/* iPhone */

@media screen and (max-width: 320pt) {
  body {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
  #portrait {
    height: 150px;
  }
  #imagebox {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24pt;
  }
  /*
        #box {
         margin: 20pt;
        }
        
        h1 {
         font-size: 13pt;
         text-align: center;
         padding-bottom: 50px;
         font-weight: 200;
         letter-spacing: 0.3em;
         text-transform: uppercase;
        }
    */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Robert Padbury</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Robert Padbury is an Australian American Designer.">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true">

</head>

<body>
  <div id="portrait">
    <img src="logo.png" width="31" height="40" alt="Robert Padbury" />
  </div>


  <div id="box">
    <h1>Robert Padbury</h1>
    <p>G'day! I am a Freelance Australian American Designer based in San Francisco, California. I focus on Human Interface Design (UI/UX), Icon Design, Identity &amp; Branding, and Special Projects.</p>
    <p>I have worked in various capacities for companies including <a href="http://www.apple.com/">Apple</a>, <a href="http://www.instagram.com/">Instagram</a>, <a href="http://www.facebook.com/">Facebook</a>, <a href="http://www.uber.com">Uber</a>, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stipple_(company)">Stipple</a>,
      <a
      href="http://www.doubletwist.com">DoubleTwist</a>, <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tapulous">Tapulous</a>, <a href="http://www.cooliris.com">Cooliris</a>, and <a href="http://www.revision3.com">Revision3</a>. Way back in the day, I was a Production Intern for <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Play">X-Play</a>.</p>

    <p>If you would like to work together, please feel free to send me an <a href="mailto:&#114;&#111;&#98;&#101;&#114;&#116;&#64;&#112;&#97;&#100;&#98;&#117;&#114;&#121;&#46;&#109;&#101;">email</a>.</p>

    <h2>Projects</h2>
    <ul class="social">
      <li><a href="http://padbury.me/clock/">Clock Screen Saver for OS X</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/padbury/atelier-playing-cards">Atelier Playing Cards</a> &mdash; <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1p2MvVyAUzEZf6PWc8iZDT2Vsbskfaf4cAurJf_QbzmM/viewform?usp=send_form">Waiting List</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="https://www.buyolympia.com/q/Item=rands-v3">Rands in Repose T-Shirt</a> &mdash; <a href="https://www.buyolympia.com/q/Item=rands-v3-special-gun-metal">Limited Edition</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.snapchat.com/add/modelhousetv">Model House Ibiza on Snapchat</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <h2>Social Media</h2>
    <ul class="social">
      <li><a href="https://workingnotworking.com/padbury">Working Not Working</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.instagram.com/padbury">Instagram</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.dribbble.com/padbury">Dribbble</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/padbury">Twitter</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/padbury">LinkedIn</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1599346/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1">IMDB</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <p>Photo by <a href="https://twitter.com/tristan">Tristan O&#8217;Tierney</a>.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

How can I fix this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this media query `@media screen and (max-width: 640pt)` change this:
`width: 100%` to this `max-width: 100%;`. I tested it on your site, and it work.

Comment: Thank you Fralec. I've missed this :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `<div id="portrait">` overflows the parent container. Look at the media query for iPad, your #portrait element has padding-left: 40px **plus** width: 100%, so, its actual width is 40px more than the width of its parent:

```
#portrait { 
    ...
    width: 100%;
    ...
    padding-left:40px;
    ...
}
```

You have several solutions:

1. You can add `box-sizing: border-box` property to #portrait rule, so, its width will be calculated another way - not pretty, but rather relevant solution.
2. You can just remove padding-left: 40px property (IMHO, most relevant in your case)
3. You may use calc function (just an example of a solution, irrelevant here):

   #portrait { 
         width: calc(100% - 40px)
    }